# Is there a thermodynamic cycle used where energy is extracted when the gas condenses to a liquid?

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

I was trying to calculate the energy efficiency of such a cycle, but I'm not sure how it depends on the input and output temperature difference, which doesn't seem right.

The cycle I was thinking of is as follows:

Water is moved against the hot source >100°C, and expands into steam, expanding a piston.

Steam is moved against the cold source, and condenses. As the steam condenses, the piston contracts, and pulls a generator, etc, producing some work.

So what would be the energy efficiency of such a cycle?

Comment: How about a refrigeration cycle?

Comment: Heat transfer can only occur at a certain rate.  The device you describe would probably be far to slow to be useful, regardless of its efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost describing the operation of the original [Newcomen Atmospheric Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcomen_atmospheric_engine).  In that case the steam was generated and used to lift the piston, then as the piston was near the top of its stroke, a small valve was opened injecting water into the engine which caused the steam bubble to rapidly collapse which caused the pressure in the engine to be less than atmospheric pressure, which then forced the piston down.  This engine design was the first to have industrial use and when connected to a pumping mechanism was used to pump water from mines.

It was highly inefficient, which led [James Watt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Watt) to improve the overall design of the steam engine by adding a condenser to the overall cycle which significantly improved performance and efficiency.

There are different resources online which provide [calculations of efficiency of Newcomen Atmospheric Engines](http://wwwcourses.sens.buffalo.edu/mae431/ES12Ch06.pdf).  The linked presentation calculates efficiency at roughly 3%.